# Why the classname contradicts with interned string comparison using "=="?

Tags: java, classname, string-interning

```
class helloworld
{
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       String str1="hello";
       String str2="world";
       String str=str1+str2;
       str.intern();
       System.out.println(str=="helloworld");
   }
}
```

**o/p: false**

After Executing the program it produces **false** as output.if **equals()** is used instead of **"=="** it returns true.why so?

2.In this case after changing classname it produces **true** as output.

```
class main
{
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       String str1="hello";
       String str2="world";
       String str=str1+str2;
       str.intern();
       System.out.println(str=="helloworld");
  }
}
```

**o/p:true**

Why the contradiction occurs b/w interned string comparison using **"=="** with classname (in case of comparison string name is used as classname)?

Comment: Look up string interning

Comment: This is just so that you give up using == and use String.equals()

Comment: Actually this is a very interesting question, +1. It's not what you think guys, see @DavidWallace answer.

Comment: It's an extremely interesting question.  The only reason to downvote it is failure to have understood it.

Comment: Has anyone tried the examples given above? For me, both yield "false" as i would expect anyway!

Comment: If the OP hadn't observed this behaviour, they wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that in the first example, the string `"helloworld"` is already in the string pool, on account of its being the name of the class.  So interning it doesn't add anything to the string pool.  So `str` won't be the interned value, and the comparison will be false.

In the second example, `str.intern()` actually adds `str` to the string pool, because `"helloworld"` is not already there.  Then, when the `"helloworld"` literal is encountered, the string object that's actually used is the one that's in the string pool.  That's just `str`, so the comparison will be true.

Comment: @david classname also be stored to string pool uh?

Comment: Yes, class names go in the string pool.  I don't know why.

Comment: that also makes me fuzzy

Comment: The reason is probably so that classloaders can use `==` instead of `equals` when they're finding the definition of a class, among the classes that are already loaded.  That would be good for performance, I guess, because a classloader would need to do this comparison whenever byte code contains any reference to any class.  In other words, all the time.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? For me, both examples yield `false` as output (as i would expect)?

Comment: Sorry, this answer doesn't make sense at all! For both cases, "helloworld" would be in the string pool, as it is used as String literal in both classes. `str.intern()` is a no-op in both cases (the returned interned string is discarded, so `str` remaind unchanged. And as i said, i cant repeat the behaviour in the question anyway...

Comment: It's not the same in every JVM.  Some JVMs intern the literals before running through the code; others only intern the literals when they come to them.

Comment: @Gyro Gearless: there’s a difference in the behavior of `intern()` between Java 6 and Java 7. I think that’s because in Java 6 a `String` may be a sub-string of a larger `String`— or it’s just a simplification of the implementation. However in the Java 7 implementation I tested it always returns `true`, so the class name was not added to the constant pool, in other words `str=="helloworld"` returned `true` while `str==helloworld.class.getName()` returned `false`. The literals were added on the first use so putting a `String dummy="helloworld";` at the beginning of the method changed the game.

Answer (score 3):

`String` is immutable. You must use the return value of `str.intern()`. Just calling `str.intern()` and ignoring the return value does nothing.

```
str = str.intern();
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing answers, here a nice articles about intern()

English: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/06/26/all-about-intern

Russian: http://habrahabr.ru/post/79913/

Answer (score -1):

String in an immutable Object. And as of intern() function as per javadoc

```
When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
string equal to this <code>String</code> object as determined by
the {@link #equals(Object)} method, then the string from the pool is
returned. Otherwise, this <code>String</code> object is added to the
pool and a reference to this <code>String</code> object is returned.
```

So you must assign the return value Eg `string = string.intern();`

As for your output it should be `true` irrespective of your class name because as mentioned above it has nothing to do with calling intern().

Comment: The question asked why it WASN'T the same, in the two cases.  Asserting that it SHOULD be the same isn't answering the question.  -1.

Comment: @aniket by making str=str.intern(); returns true but why the classname contradicts with str.intern(); ?

Comment: What David has posted in answer sounds logically correct but I wish I could see the string(Class name) in string pool. When I tried I got true in both cases(I am using Java 7). If you really getting the behavior you have posted that Davids answer may be the best possible explanation but I would recommend try it in another environment.

Comment: in java 7 may be the class name was not added to the string constant pool.yur ans was helpful (: